# which openmp schedule am I running?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

How to check in runtime the openmp schedule?

I compile my code with a parallel loop and runtime scheduele

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime) collapse(2)
for(j=1;j>-2;j-=2){
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    //nested loop code here
    }
}
```

and I specify the environment variable `OMP_SCHEDULE=dynamic,50`.

How can I check in runtime that my program actually took the `OMP_SCHEDULE`variable ?

I am using openmp 3.1 with gcc 4.7.3

Comment: Wasn't there an openmp api function that outputs all runtime info when the program is ran? I couldn't get a hand on it.

Comment: `void omp_get_schedule(omp_sched_t *kind, int *chunk_size)`

Comment: @Z Boson, make it an answer and point him at the standard! (I just started writing that answer myself, but don't want to steal your thunder :-))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I downloaded http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf

Then went to the section "C/C++ Stub Routines" and found this

```
void omp_get_schedule(omp_sched_t *kind, int *chunk_size)
{
*kind = omp_sched_static;
*chunk_size = 0;
}
```

Then made this test

```
/*                                                                                                                                                                            
  typedef enum omp_sched_t {                                                                                                                                                  
    omp_sched_static = 1,                                                                                                                                                     
    omp_sched_dynamic = 2,                                                                                                                                                    
    omp_sched_guided = 3,                                                                                                                                                     
    omp_sched_auto = 4                                                                                                                                                        
  } omp_sched_t;                                                                                                                                                              
*/

#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  omp_sched_t kind;
  int chunk;
  omp_get_schedule(&kind, &chunk);
  printf("%d %d\n", kind, chunk);
}
```

and compiled

```
gcc -fopenmp -O3 foo.c
```

and then

```
export OMP_SCHEDULE=static,50
./a.out
1 50
export OMP_SCHEDULE=dynamic,100
2 100
```

Note that `omp_get_schedule` only reports the runtime scheduling definition `OMP_SCHEDULE`. If you change the scheduling with e.g.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
```

and define `OMP_SCHEDULE=dynamic,100` then `omp_get_schedule` still reports dynamic scheduling and chunk size 100.